# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFieldProps') with the FastField in formik

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I have a form with the Formik and I am going to decrease re-renders so I used the FastField.
I got the error  `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFieldProps')` and I don't have an idea how I can solve it.

there is full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-butterfly-95mx1d?file=/index.js:0-894)

I found about it [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/fastfield) and [here](https://codereacter.medium.com/reducing-the-number-of-renders-when-using-formik-9790bf111ab9)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useFormik, FastField } from "formik";
import * as yup from "yup";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const validationSchema = yup.object({});

const WithMaterialUI = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName:''
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <FastField name="firstName" placeholder="Weezy" />
        <Button color="primary" variant="contained" fullWidth type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<WithMaterialUI />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormik) you'll find

> ** Be aware that , , , connect(), and  will NOT work with useFormik() as they all require React Context.

So you can't keep using the hook if you want to use `<FastField/>`, so I guess you have to fallback to the old style of wrapping your form with `<Formik>` component